# Spurious warning gcc -Wuninitialized

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

OS:  Debian 9

compiler:  gcc 8.2.0 (installed from buster (testing) repository)

I know that using things from debian testing branch is dangerous, but debian testing is *usually stable*, and gcc 8.2 has been released as stable, so it shouldn't have many bugs.

in this function:

```
int user_tui        (const char *title, const char *subtitle)
{
    int action;
//  action  = USER_IFACE_ACT_FOO;

    show_help();
    user_tui_show_log(title, subtitle);
    action  = usr_input();

    return  action;
}
```

It is reporting the following error (`-Wall -Werror` and also `-O3 -march=native`):

```
/.../modules//user//src//user_tui.c: In function ‘user_tui’:
/.../modules//user//src//user_tui.c:91:9: error: ‘action’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  return action;
         ^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

When I uncomment the initialization, the error is still there.  I think it shouldn't even be needed, as there is no conditional or anything that would ever block the assignment `action = usr_input();`.

Is it a spurious warning, or is it legit?

I would say it is a bug in gcc;  it can't even be considered spurious.

Comment: Show the definition of `usr_input` function.

Comment: Really no conditions, also not in usr_input() itself, maybe by using exceptions which running out of the initializing scope? BTW "gcc 8.2 has been released as stable, so it shouldn't have many bugs." is definitly wrong if you look in the bugtracker. There are "some" open bugs, some are open and unfixed for multiple major versions... But you are right, such an easy to see bug I also would not expect.

Comment: @Maxim You were right, I had to look inside `usr_input()`. But I would say that the variable returned by `usr_input()` is the one that is being used uninitialized, and not `action` itself. `action` is really being initialized, although with garbage in the case of an uninitialized return of `usr_input()`. I would call that a bug in gcc.

Comment: Please don't change the topic. Instead use the `Accept` button at the answer that solved your problem. That's the way how StackOverflow works. It's also okay to `accept` the own answer.

Comment: Ok.  However, as the answer is mine, I can't until 2 days from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MaximEgorushkin for noting that I should look inside `usr_input()`.

The error is in `usr_input()` and not in `user_tui()`.

It has a very long switch with many switches inside, and in one of them I forgot the `default:` entry.

So lesson: look recursively inside functions to see if they are really initialized.

I think gcc should let us know that!